# import django cms as app into existing django project

Tags: django, django-templates, content-management-system, django-cms

Hi I have already an existing project into django, now I want to use django cms for dynamic web pages and to gain many more functionality, but not able to find anywhere, how could I use django cms project as app into my django project. can anybody help me out, thanks.

Comment: Hi Prashant, did you successfully import Django-CMS into your project? I'm sorry to bother but I'm trying to do the same and would like to know if following the suggested tutorial did the trick for you.. Thank you in adavnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tutorial should cover your needs:

[Installing django CMS by hand](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/install.html)

You should be able to install all the packages and dependencies without any problems, you only need to amend the URL setup to accommodate both for your existing app(s) and Django CMS.